# Calendar.before() returns wrong value

Tags: java

The main idea of the following code is to compare two dates with a precision of 1 minute.

`rc` is the reference time and `tc` is the time to test:

```
// Checking precision of 1 minute
Calendar upperBound, lowerBound;
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");

upperBound = (Calendar)rc.clone();
upperBound.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
lowerBound = (Calendar)rc.clone();
lowerBound.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);

//Actual values
System.out.println("test "+dateFormat.format(tc.getTime()));
System.out.println("UpperB"+dateFormat.format(upperBound.getTime()));
System.out.println("LowerB "+dateFormat.format(lowerBound.getTime()));
//Tests
System.out.println("test after "+tc.after(lowerBound));
System.out.println("test before "+tc.before(upperBound));
```

And the output is the following:

```
test 05/10/2015 09:43.

UpperB 05/10/2015 09:44.

LowerB 05/10/2015 09:42.

test after false.

test before true.
```

I'm very confused, because the `Calendar.after()` comparison of the test date with the lower bound returns `false`, where it should be `true` by the dates printed before.

Any ideas, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What's `rc` and `tc`? Where are they defined? Have you tried a different format? Are these times pm or am?

Comment: What do you see when printing the getTimeInMillis() of each calendar?

Comment: As @toniedzwiedz asks ... rc is cloned but tc is tested.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with `Calendar rc = Calendar.getInstance(); Calendar tc = (Calendar) rc.clone();`, both checks are true then.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz both rc and tc are created in the following way:
Calendar rc=Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar tc=Calendar.getInstance();

rc.setTime(dateFormat.format("05/10/2015 09:43"));

tc.setTime(dateFormat.format("05/10/2015 09:43"));

Comment: Please don't attempt to put code in the comments. Add information to the question itself, and format it properly.

Comment: `Calendar rc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); Calendar tc = (Calendar) rc.clone(); tc.add(Calendar.HOUR, -12);` brings up false/true, what's right, but looks wrong because the difference is covered as am/pm is missing on println - as toniedzwiedz suspected.

Comment: @AndresCamiloJimenez Supposed you mean parse instead of format there, I cannot reproduce your results.

Comment: @AndresCamiloJimenez that line doesn't make sense. The types don't check out. `DateFormat#format` returns a `String` or a `StringBuffer` but `Calendar#setTime` expects a `Date` object.

Comment: @yasd yes you are right, i wrote it wrong sorry.

Comment: And @toniedzwiedz you were right also checking if it was am or pm,i checked it with the format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a" and with "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", and worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test with JDK 1.8:

```
        Calendar tc = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar rc = Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar upperBound, lowerBound;
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");

        upperBound = (Calendar) rc.clone();
        upperBound.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        lowerBound = (Calendar) rc.clone();
        lowerBound.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);

        //Actual values
        System.out.println("test " + dateFormat.format(tc.getTime()));
        System.out.println("UpperB " + dateFormat.format(upperBound.getTime()));
        System.out.println("LowerB " + dateFormat.format(lowerBound.getTime()));
        //Tests
        System.out.println("test after " + tc.after(lowerBound));
        System.out.println("test before " + tc.before(upperBound));
```

output:

```
test 08/11/2015 05:34
UpperB 08/11/2015 05:35
LowerB 08/11/2015 05:33
test after true
test before true
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: That's still not an answer. "Works for me on Java 8" may be added as a comment to the question, not as an answer.

Comment: you want answer like "he is liar"?

Comment: No, StackOverflow requires an answer which actually answers the question or provides a solution to the problem in the question. If such an answer is not available, then nothing should be posted as an answer.

Comment: answer that code he provided is ok - also answer, so he can search another places of his code for bugs

Comment: Nah, this is a good answer. It's perfectly fine to Stack Overflow standards @RealSkeptic